# Ensure IIS 7 Remote Management is configured for all domain-joined IIS servers

Tags: iis-7, group-policy

The article at the following URL describes installing and configuring the Web Management Service to allow an IIS 7 instance to be managed from a remote machine.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/158/remote-administration-for-iis-manager/

I don't want to have to repeat these steps manually for every IIS server so I'd rather create a Group Policy to do this for me but I can't find any documentation on how to configure this service via Group Policy.

Has anyone already found a way?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2 there is option to easly put registry items inside Group policy.
So, create group policy, and in Computer configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry, create a new Registry item: (update)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Path: Software\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server
Key: EnableRemoteManagement
Type: dword
Value: 1 (hex)

And in Computer configuration > Policies > Windows settings > Security Settings > System services , put the service: Web management service to Automaticaly start